# Azure MVC4 app: Getting NullReferenceException in System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-roles

I have implemented a custom membership and role provider for my website that work fine when running locally using the Azure emulator, but once deployed to the cloud, I get the following exception upon opening the site:

`[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.Security.Membership.GetCurrentUserName() +60`

The following SO question sheds some light on the implementation of GetCurrentUserName:  [Why am I getting a NullReferenceException from Membership.GetCurrentUserName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663018/why-am-i-getting-a-nullreferenceexception-from-membership-getcurrentusername)

Does anyone have some insight as to why this would happen once deployed to the cloud?

Comment: Is it an aync await function ?

Comment: It is not.  Everything is being done on the thread handling the request.